# Android - Add an item from one ListView to another ListView?

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, rss

I have an app that shows news from a RSS feed. There is ListView-1 which loads the news and when you click on an item(news), it shows only the selected news in a seperated xml layout. On the ActionBar for the single news item layout, user can click on Add to Favourites.

I have another activity and layout file and a listview just for Favourites. How can I copy an item from one listview to another?

So, the user can add news from main ListView-1 to another list called ListView-2.

I cannot use intents for sending one list item.
I have been thinking of using SharedPreferences to share an ArrayList, but something else needs to be the solution.

Comment: why you can't send list with intent? i think better way is using `sqlite` for saving favorites values.

Comment: because i don't want to send the user to another activity when clicked on the "Add to Bookmarks". I want the user to stay on the single news layout file. When the user clicks on "Add to Bookmarks", it should just show a message that the news have been added to Bookmarks. The process of copying the list item from ListView-1 to ListView-2 should be done in background.

Comment: where you saved all favorite value? in database? so why you don't put this too? 2 listView is in same activity ?

Comment: the items of ListView-1 is stored in an ArrayList, but that's coming from a RSS feed. Database-SQL is not used in my app yet.

Comment: so when user add one news to Favorite then exit from app, how you save this news?

Comment: ohh i see what you mean. I need to use SQL, right? but what kind of method should i use when the user clicks on "Add to Favourites"? what kind of android logarithm should i use, to send the item from one class to another, from one listview to another listview?

Comment: you need sqlite. you need add id of news or any key to database after user clicked on add to favorite, thin in second activity you just need one query to database for reading all id, and showing that to user

Comment: okay, but this is loading from RSS. so, how do i know which news i should give the ID?

Comment: what is data struct of RSS? what data you get from that? did that have an unique id ? you need save that

Comment: title, date, description, author, no no unique id comes from RSS.

Comment: if don't come you need add that too, if you can't add you can use key with multiple some value like, date+author = key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need intents, just separate view and data, keep news in the singleton class, for example NewsManager, and keep one list for all news, one for favourite news, and use favourite list in the ListView2 adapter

Comment: but how do I add one item from ListView1 to ListView2?

Comment: It must be done in the Manager class, and then call notifyDataSetChanged function on the ListView2 adapter, ListView only shows data, it is intended to show only data, and data manipulation do in the data class, in this case, in the NewsManager
for example

NewsManager.getInstance().addFavouriteNews(n);
listView2Adapter.notifyOnDataSetChanged();

Comment: but i need to use SQl to save the favourites? after exiting app, everything should be saved.

Comment: Yes, saving and loading also do in the NewsManager class, it owns the news items, ant it must save and load them, view class only may call methods on it to save or load

Comment: how about saving the item in a txt file on the phone with I/O? would it be easier? or SQL is better?

Comment: Saving in the txt file is the easier solution, but SQL is better solution, because with SQL you can query for specific news, update, insert or delete single item, and SQL engine will do it effectively, without revritting entire database file. With txt file, app must revrite all news even on single update

Comment: okay, but my listview loads stuff (title,date..) from RSS. so how will i be able to add ID to news, i don't sepcificially know yet.

Comment: You manipulate all data in the view (Activity or Fragment), which is not good, because view's lifetime manages system, it can destroy when screen orientation changes, or when it goes to background, that's why it's not good to store data in the view, all time it will load entire content from the DB. You must have class News, which will hold ID ,and other properties of the news.

Comment: so you are saying, that the things from RSS should be loaded to a SQL database? because right now, it's just a listview with custum adapter and rss parsers. so what should I change?

Comment: You should move parse function to the manager class, I assume that You already have class News (for single news), News Manager (that holds all news, parse function and maybe other methods for manipulating news items), I've already said, that the function of the view is only to show items, and, of course, call corresponding functions from the NewsManager, but implementation, like insert, update, delete, save, load, etc... must do in the manager class, manager class also allows to use data in the multiple views, without copy paste its logic