# How to add a listview item to a whole other listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

So in my android app, I have two scrollable tabs which each contain Listview using a Fragment. One a list of apps and the other is blank. What I am aiming to do is add a plus button in place of where my checkbox is and duplicate that item in the other listview which is blank.

[image]

[image]

I have done research on this, but I have not found any successful examples on how to implement this.

[Android - Add an item from one ListView to another ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096836/android-add-an-item-from-one-listview-to-another-listview)

Here is my fragment that returns the apps

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app.ApkAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;



public class InstalledAppActivity extends Fragment
        implements OnItemClickListener {

    PackageManager packageManager;
    ListView apkList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_installed, container, false);
        packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();


        /*To filter out System apps*/

        apkList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.applist);

        new LoadApplications(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).execute();


        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * Return whether the given PackageInfo represents a system package or not.
     * User-installed packages (Market or otherwise) should not be denoted as
     * system packages.
     *
     * @param pkgInfo
     * @return boolean
     */
    private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
                : false;
    }

    private boolean isSystemPackage1(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) != 0) ? false
                : true;
    }


// Don't need in Fragment
/*@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.block, menu);
   // super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}*/

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }


    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        Context mContext;

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        List<PackageInfo> packageList1 = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

        public LoadApplications(Context context){
            Context mContext = context;
        }




        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
                    .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);


          /*  List<ApplicationInfo> list = mContext.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);


            for(int n = 0;n<list.size();n++){
                if ((list.get(n).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP))
            }*/


            for(PackageInfo pi : packageList) {
                boolean b = isSystemPackage(pi);
                boolean c = isSystemPackage1(pi);

                if(!b || !c ) {
                    packageList1.add(pi);
                }
            }

            //sort by application name

            final PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator comparator = new PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager);

            Collections.sort(packageList1, new Comparator<PackageInfo>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(PackageInfo lhs, PackageInfo rhs) {
                    return comparator.compare(lhs.applicationInfo, rhs.applicationInfo);
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(InstalledAppActivity.this.getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading your apps...");
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            apkList.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(getActivity(), packageList1, packageManager));

            if (pDialog.isShowing()){
                pDialog.dismiss();

            }


            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

}
```

And here is my adapter class:

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.R;

import java.util.List;

public class ApkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    List<PackageInfo> packageList;
    Activity context;
    PackageManager packageManager;
    boolean[] itemChecked;

    public ApkAdapter(Activity context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
                      PackageManager packageManager) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.packageList = packageList;
        this.packageManager = packageManager;
        itemChecked = new boolean[packageList.size()];
    }



    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView apkName;
        CheckBox ck1;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return packageList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return packageList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.appname);
            holder.ck1 = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
             //holder.ck1.setTag(packageList.get(position));

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        // ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);



        Drawable appIcon = packageManager
                .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);




        String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
                packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 75, 75);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        holder.apkName.setText(appName);
        holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

        if (itemChecked[position])
            holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

        holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (holder.ck1.isChecked())
                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                else
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }




}
```

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Can't you just add it to the other array and send a `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: You should have 2 separate arraylists for this purpose. 1 would be the list of applications and the other is the list of blacklisted applications.All you need to do is to handle the click event on the checkbox and add the selected item to the blacklisted lists.
When you will swipe to the other tab the list should be drawn with the new data.

Comment: Or you can store those applications as e.g. 1 map, where PackageInfo will be a key and boolean value will represent if application is on black list or not. But I am not exactly sure it is what are you looking for

Answer (score 1):

So what you are doing is, you are populating a listview of installed apps using package manager. Add a plus button in place of the checkbox. Now get installed apps similar to this -

```
    List<PackageInfo> packageList1 = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);

    final PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator comparator = new PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager);

    Collections.sort(packageList1, new Comparator<PackageInfo>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(PackageInfo lhs, PackageInfo rhs) {
            return comparator.compare(lhs.applicationInfo, rhs.applicationInfo);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < packageList1.size(); i++) {

        PackageInfo PackInfo = packageList1.get(i);
        if (((PackInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) != true) {

            //Add to adapter
        }
    }
}
```

Now, create a public string array in the activity which is holding the tabs. When you click on the plus button add the packagename to the array.

Now on the other tab use the same adapter, but here before adding it to the adapter check if it is found in the string array using the index. Something like -

```
List<PackageInfo> packageList1 = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);

final PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator comparator = new PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager);

Collections.sort(packageList1, new Comparator<PackageInfo>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(PackageInfo lhs, PackageInfo rhs) {
        return comparator.compare(lhs.applicationInfo, rhs.applicationInfo);
    }
});

for (int i = 0; i < packageList1.size(); i++) {

    PackageInfo PackInfo = packageList1.get(i);
    if (((PackInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) != true) {
    if (Mainactivity.array contains String PackageName= PackInfo.packageName)
    {
                //Add to adapter
    }
            }
}
    }
```

To persist the selected apps, add their package name to shared_preferences.

edit :

In your fragment's LoadApplications class, you retrieve a list of installed apps. On the second fragment use the same code, but just add one more condition

```
    for(PackageInfo pi : packageList) {
            boolean b = isSystemPackage(pi);
            boolean c = isSystemPackage1(pi);

            if(!b || !c ) {

    if (array contains packagename){
    packageList1.add(pi);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just a bit confused on how this is all implemented.Can you further explain the relationship between the 1st block of code and the 2nd block and how this all works together? And this is all intended to be implemented in my current adapter class right? And I thought I already got the installed apps

Comment: Sorry couldn't get the answer in comments so added it to my answer

Comment: I see. Makes sense. I'm just trying to figure out what to put in my onclicklistener for the plus

Comment: Try something like this
`List<String> blacklist = new ArrayList<String>();`

and on onClick add

`blacklist.add(pi.packageName)`

Comment: okay I see. and about the for loop (for (int i = 0; i < packageList1.size(); i++) { ) I would put that in the blank fragment right?

Comment: Don't worry about my code, just check for the presence of package name in the String list like in the bottom edit of my answe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58387/discussion-between-xijiaopin-and-user3106978).

Answer (score 0):

```
List<UserApps> packageListBlocked = new ArrayList<UserApps>();
holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (holder.ck1.isChecked())
            itemChecked[position] = true;
            packageListBlocked.add(packageList.get(position));
        else
            itemChecked[position] = false;
    }
});
```

ArrayList can hold duplicate data, so be cautious while adding.

Now you have all checkedItems in `packageListBlocked` pass it on to next tab and set data, make sure you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`